# Excel formula - list the standard for each product

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of products, let’s say AAA, ABC, BCD, 321, K13, and so son.
Their specifications are slightly different for each customer.
So I have a list of products by customer, something like this:

[image]

I need to find the “standard” for each specification for each product.

I mean, for each product, how is each field in the majority of customers.

For the list above it would be:

[image]

Even if there is in fact no customer with all those specifications together.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What version are you using, Excel Online or a installable version like Excel 2016?

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/most-frequently-occurring-text

Comment: It isn't clear how you define "standard", or how you want to derive it from the data.  Typically, you would define the standard and then perhaps allow customers to deviate from it, but you would look up the standard in your own table.  Are you trying to back into something based on the predominant pattern?  If so, what is the threshold?  The most frequent choice by column (could represent a small minority of customers)?  A majority of customers for that item?  What if exactly half of the customers choose one way and the others choose the opposite?

Comment: I'm not working on line, but I might use google-sheets if necessary. I have Excel 97-2003 Workbook, but I can use Macro-Enabled if useful.

Comment: I understand that the standard should have been defined before and only then customers would be allowed to deviate from it, but unfortunately this didn’t happen. I found the data as it is, and now I have to find out what is the standard that makes sense.
So, yes, I’m trying to back into something based on the predominant pattern. That would be the most frequent choice by column, by product.
If half of the customers choose one way and the others choose the opposite, any of the two options will do, with no problem.

Comment: exceljet.net/formula/most-frequently-occurring-text would work if I add just one product, but I have more than four thousand products, I cannot do it one by one. The outcome has to be a list of products...

Comment: @CeuMelo: that's the first step also you need to put effort in it.

Comment: I've been using the formula INDEX(A6:A64; MODE(MATCH(A6:A64; A6:A64; 0))) [in this case the product has 64 customers]. This means I'm doing it product by product. I'm asking your help, because I don't know how to compile the information for all the products at the same time. Thank you in advance for your help.